# Joining three tables and create new column

Tags: sql, sql-server

"*Categories*":

| ID | product_category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | sweets |
| 2 | kitchen utensils |

"*Stores*":

| store_id | store_name |
| --- | --- |
| a11 | ABC |
| a22 | DFG |

"*Sales*":

| product_code | bonus_card | store_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3334 | TRUE | a11 |
| 8388 | FALSE | a22 |

"*Products*":

| produ_code | product_name | category_id | store_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3334 | AAA | 1 | a11 |
| 8388 | BBB | 2 | a22 |

I need to find which department of store has the max bonus card uses (it can be rank also).

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT category.product_category, 
       store.store_id
INNER JOIN product1
        ON product1.product_category = product_category;
INNER JOIN category
        ON product1.category_id = ID;
```

But I can't go on.

Can you help me with this one?

Comment: there is no department in any column

Answer (score 1):

First you need to have the number of sales with bonus card. I don't know if you need it as a total or as a percentage but I'm assuming you want the maximum total sales.

```
select store_name, product_category, count(1) as sales_made from (Select * from sales where bonus_Card = true) a
inner join products b on (a.product_code = b.product_code)
inner join categories c on (b.category_id = c.category_id)
inner join stores d on (b.store_id = d.store_id)
group by store_name, product_category
```

Then, considering what's above, it depends on if you need this globally or per store. You will have to partition by store_name if you need it by store.

```
select * from (
select a.*, row_number() over (/*partition by store_name*/ order by sales_made) as rn from result)
where rn = 1
```

Full query:

```
with results as (select store_name, product_category, count(1) as sales_made from (Select * from sales where bonus_Card = true) a
    inner join products b on (a.product_code = b.product_code)
    inner join categories c on (b.category_id = c.category_id)
    inner join stores d on (b.store_id = d.store_id)
    group by store_name, product_category)


    select * from (
    select a.*, row_number() over (/*partition by store_name*/ order by sales_made desc) as rn from result)
    where rn = 1
```

Comment: hm the question is very unclear, as no department exists in the tables

Comment: I am assuming that department is the product category as well

Comment: i don't know most woudl assume the store name though

Comment: Well, it says department of store, so I thought that could only be the product category

Comment: a department of a store, is a subsection of a  store, as you don't have them the question stays very unclear

Comment: I mean with departmen - category

Comment: Then this should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by :

- applying an `INNER JOIN` operation between the "*Sales*" and "*Stores*" tables
- aggregating over the Sales.bonus_card field with the [`SUM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_sum) function

```
SELECT Stores.store_name,
       SUM(Sales.bonus_card) AS num_bonus_cards 
FROM       Sales
INNER JOIN Stores
        ON Sales.store_id = Stores.store_id
GROUP BY Stores.store_name
ORDER BY num_bonus_cards DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0de7fb2c7e7503e991f998fab82ad8e3).

Comment: i ran it but i gives 0.0 as num_bonus_cards

Comment: how does the definition of the fiddle tables differ from your tables? @bba

Comment: there is no difference, maybe can be where bonus_card= true

Comment: because i need only when bonus card is used that case is TRUE,but how should i add it?

Comment: When `SUM` is applied to `Sales.bonus_card`, it will cast the boolean types to integers: (`TRUE` -> 1, `FALSE` -> 0). Hence, applying the sum will essentially result in counting cases when `bonus_card = TRUE`.